# Upload app for iPhone ONLY ?

Tags: iphone, ios

I want my application to be available for iPhone devices only ! 
Is it allowed by Apple and if so how do I distribute it for iPhone only (besides setting the family to iPhone) ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, there's no reason why your base SDK for the ipad only target should be 3.2. In fact, since iOS 4.2 runs on ipad, you're going to limit your customer base by not changing the base SDK to 4.2. You can set your target OS to iOS 3.2 to make sure the app will run on iOS 3.2.

In your target configuration build settings, look for "targeted device family", that will say whether or not the target is "ipad", "iphone" or (for universal apps) "iphone/ipad".

I also migrated a universal app to two separate targets -- it was not fun. You have to very carefully check your build settings and your .plist files to make sure they're sane for their intended target device, especially check:Base SDK, iOS deployment target, targeted device family, and Info.plist file